# Mismatching route for rspec testing post on a singular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I get the error no routes matches even tho in rake routes I have:

`... POST /todo/:todo/todo_comments(.:format)`

and in my rspec I have

`post :todo_comments, params: { todo_id: 1 }`

Comment: Shouldn't you use the path?, `todo_comments` is just the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your routes are defined as:

```
resources :todos do
  resources :todo_comments
end
```

---

In a **controller spec** (`type: :controller`), you need to specify the action name in the controller that handles the request. In this case, that's `:index`:

```
post :index, params: { todo_id: 1 }
```

---

If you're in a **request spec** (`type: :request`), on the other hand, it requires the URL to request instead, which you can build using a routing helper:

```
post todo_todo_comments_path(1)

# or, without the helper:
post "/todos/1/todo_comments"
```

Note that these forms don't explicitly name the `:todo_id` parameter, because it will be extracted from the route.